# Issues with downloading dict into CSV accesing NY Times API via Python

Tags: python, api, csv

I am currently trying to download a large number of NY Times articles using their API, based on Python 2.7. To do so, I was able to reuse a piece of code i found online:

```
[code]from nytimesarticle import articleAPI
api = articleAPI('...')

articles = api.search( q = 'Brazil', 
     fq = {'headline':'Brazil', 'source':['Reuters','AP', 'The New York Times']}, 
     begin_date = '20090101' )

def parse_articles(articles):
    '''
    This function takes in a response to the NYT api and parses
    the articles into a list of dictionaries
    '''
    news = []
    for i in articles['response']['docs']:
        dic = {}
        dic['id'] = i['_id']
        if i['abstract'] is not None:
            dic['abstract'] = i['abstract'].encode("utf8")
        dic['headline'] = i['headline']['main'].encode("utf8")
        dic['desk'] = i['news_desk']
        dic['date'] = i['pub_date'][0:10] # cutting time of day.
        dic['section'] = i['section_name']
        if i['snippet'] is not None:
            dic['snippet'] = i['snippet'].encode("utf8")
        dic['source'] = i['source']
        dic['type'] = i['type_of_material']
        dic['url'] = i['web_url']
        dic['word_count'] = i['word_count']
        # locations
        locations = []
        for x in range(0,len(i['keywords'])):
            if 'glocations' in i['keywords'][x]['name']:
                locations.append(i['keywords'][x]['value'])
        dic['locations'] = locations
        # subject
        subjects = []
        for x in range(0,len(i['keywords'])):
            if 'subject' in i['keywords'][x]['name']:
                subjects.append(i['keywords'][x]['value'])
        dic['subjects'] = subjects   
        news.append(dic)
    return(news)

def get_articles(date,query):
    '''
    This function accepts a year in string format (e.g.'1980')
    and a query (e.g.'Amnesty International') and it will 
    return a list of parsed articles (in dictionaries)
    for that year.
    '''
    all_articles = []
    for i in range(0,100): #NYT limits pager to first 100 pages. But rarely will you find over 100 pages of results anyway.
        articles = api.search(q = query,
               fq = {'headline':'Brazil','source':['Reuters','AP', 'The New York Times']},
               begin_date = date + '0101',
               end_date = date + '1231',
               page = str(i))
        articles = parse_articles(articles)
        all_articles = all_articles + articles
    return(all_articles)

Download_all = []
for i in range(2009,2010):
    print 'Processing' + str(i) + '...'
    Amnesty_year =  get_articles(str(i),'Brazil')
    Download_all = Download_all + Amnesty_year

import csv
keys = Download_all[0].keys()
with open('brazil-mentions.csv', 'wb') as output_file:
    dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(output_file, keys)
    dict_writer.writeheader()
    dict_writer.writerows(Download_all)
```

Without the last bit (starting with "... import csv" this seems to be working fine. If I simply print my results, ("print Download_all") I can see them, however in a very unstructured way. Running the actual code i however get the message:

```
  File "C:\Users\xxx.yyy\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\csv.py", line 148, in _dict_to_list
    + ", ".join([repr(x) for x in wrong_fields]))

ValueError: dict contains fields not in fieldnames: 'abstract'
```

Since I am quite a newbie at this, I would highly appreciate your help in guiding me how to download the news articles into a csv file in a structured way.

Thanks a lot in advance!
Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where you have:

```
keys = Download_all[0].keys()
```

This takes the column headers for the CSV from the dictionary for the first article. The problem is that the article dictionaries do not all have the same keys, so when you reach the first one that has the extra `abstract` key, it fails.

It looks like you'll have problems with `abstract` and `snippet` which are only added to the dictionary if they exist in the response.

You need to make `keys` equal to the superset of all possible keys:

```
keys = Download_all[0].keys() + ['abstract', 'snippet']
```

Or, ensure that every dict has a value for every field:

```
def parse_articles(articles):
    ...
    if i['abstract'] is not None:
        dic['abstract'] = i['abstract'].encode("utf8")
    else:
        dic['abstract'] = ""
    ...
    if i['snippet'] is not None:
        dic['snippet'] = i['snippet'].encode("utf8")
    else:
        dic['snippet'] = ""
```